# how do I indicate an unset default parameter of type Number in Flex3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

for String and Object type, I can set the default parameter to null to indicate that it was not set by the caller.  Is there a mechanism in flex3 to do the same for the Number type?

So for instance:
    public function myMethod( stringVar:String=null, ObjectVar:Object=null, numberVar:Number ) 
    {
    ...
    }

I could do the following, but it just feels ugly

```
public function myMethod( numberVarObj:Object=null ) 
{
 var numberVarSet:Boolean=true;
if( numberVarObj == null ) {
     numberVarSet = false;
 }

 and then everywhere I want to use numberVar I can check for numberVarSet and cast as a Number.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could always try:

```
var numberVar:* = null;
```

And then set it to a number when you want . . . It would be nice to have a solution that is strongly typed though.

Another option, as specified in [Adobe's Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_07.html) (scroll down to default values), would be to treat the value NaN as null.  However, if your data has ANY chance of containing a NaN value, this is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the "ugly" solution you have, but if you really want another option you can use NaN and then use isNaN(num) to check the value.